# Select from XML with unknown structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 with the following structure:

```
id     = int
numero = int
datos  = xml
[other_misc_fields]
```

You can see the table with some example data on this [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5408e/1). As you can see on the link, the field **datos** (data) is an XML. This XML doesn't have a known structure. All I know is that the root is "lote" and that every field has an attribute "title" which is the "display name" of the field. I would like to be able to query something along this line

```
id | numero | display_name_field_1 | display_name_field_2 | display_name_field_3
 1 |   23   |     value_field_1    |     value_field_2    |     value_field_3
```

Using some [dynamic sql](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) (from [another so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604854/query-xml-creating-field-names-whithout-knowing-node-names)) I'm able to get the value from each node, but I can't figure out how to rename it using the title attribute:

```
select @SQL = 'select '+stuff(
  (
  select ',T.N.value('''+T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname')+'[1]'', ''varchar(max)'') as '+T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname')
  from @XML.nodes('/*[local-name(.)=sql:variable("@KnownName")]/*') as T(N)
  for xml path(''), type
  ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')+
  ' from @XML.nodes(''/*[local-name(.)=sql:variable("@KnownName")]'') as T(N)
```

Where @KnownName is "lote".

How can I modify that query so the field renames to the **@title** attribute of the node? Or, alternatively, is there a better way to do this than dynamic sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was relatively easy to do. The only issue is that column names can't be easily set to a dynamic value. Finally, I decided to deal with the XML client side, but this is a way to do something similar to what I wanted, in case anyone is interested:

```
SELECT @SQL = 'select '+stuff(
      (
      SELECT ',T.N.value('''+T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname')+'[1]'',''varchar(max)'') as '+ T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname')+',  T.N.value(''('+T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname')+'/@title)[1]'+''',''varchar(max)'') as '+ T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname')+'@title'
      FROM @XML.nodes('/*[local-name(.)=sql:variable("@KnownName")]/*') AS T(N)
      FOR xml path(''), TYPE
      ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')+
      ' from @XML.nodes(''/*[local-name(.)=sql:variable("@KnownName")]'') as T(N)'
```

You can see it "in action" in this sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5408e/13/0

Comment: I'm dealing with a similar issue; i.e. shredding xml of an unknown structure.

This helps with part of that. It seems to work only with two levels of nodes; a root and any children of root.

`<root>
    <level1a />
    <level1b />
</root>`

However, what it doesn't do that I still require is dealing with an unknown number of child nodes.

For example:
`<root>  
    <level1a />
    <level1b>
        <level2a>
            <level3a>
                <level4a >
             </level3a>
        </level2a>
    </level1b>  
</root>`